# Break circular dependency in Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to write a simple makefile for compressing and decompressing archives (the compressed archives may be modified in place, so I want to be able to replace the decompressed versions if needed).

When I try and define makefile rules for this though, it understandably tells me that I have a circular dependency.

Simplified example:

```make
init:
    echo "Turtles" > file1.txt
    echo "Lemurs" > file2.txt

compress: file1.gz file2.gz
decompress: file1.txt file2.txt

%.gz: %.txt
    gzip -k $< -c > $@
    
%.txt: %.gz
    gzip -k $< -d -c > $@

clean:
    rm -f *.txt *.gz
```

This works, but gives me warnings:

```console
$ make init
echo "Turtles" > file1.txt
echo "Lemurs" > file2.txt

$ make compress
make: Circular file1.txt <- file1.gz dependency dropped.
gzip -k file1.txt -c > file1.gz
make: Circular file2.txt <- file2.gz dependency dropped.
gzip -k file2.txt -c > file2.gz

$ make decompress
make: Circular file1.gz <- file1.txt dependency dropped.
gzip -k file1.gz -d -c > file1.txt
make: Circular file2.gz <- file2.txt dependency dropped.
gzip -k file2.gz -d -c > file2.txt
```

Is there a way to avoid the warning and achieve similar behaviour?

Comment: This really looks like `make` is not the correct tool for whatever it is that you are hoping to accomplish. The dependency graph should be acyclic. In other words, there should be a "done" state where all files are compressed, or none of them are.

Comment: @tripleee that is entirely possible; saying that my main reason for going with a makefile is for the easy parallelism (I have a lot of files) - achieving that in any of the other commonly-available tools that I'm aware of would get messy fairly quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use conditionals to break the dependency cycles:

```
.PHONY: init compress decompress clean

FILES := file1 file2

init:
    echo "Turtles" > file1.txt
    echo "Lemurs" > file2.txt

compress:
    $(MAKE) DIR=$@ $(addsuffix .gz,$(FILES))

decompress:
    $(MAKE) DIR=$@ $(addsuffix .txt,$(FILES))

ifeq ($(DIR),compress)

%.gz: %.txt
    gzip -k $< -c > $@

else ifeq ($(DIR),decompress)    

%.txt: %.gz
    gzip -k $< -d -c > $@

endif

clean:
    rm -f $(addprefix .txt,$(FILES)) $(addprefix .gz,$(FILES))
```

Comment: I ended up going with this solution which worked pretty well, although if I was doing something less trivial then the separate-makefile solution below seems like a much better way to structure my code.

Answer (score 1):

You can have the compress and decompress rules in separate makefiles:

```
$ make -f compress.mk
$ make -f decompress.mk
```

The files may `include` any common parts.